# Common techniques/resources for formatting source code?

Tags: css, formatting

Two parter:

1. Does anyone know of any stylesheets that are meant to format like visual studio, also any that format like chrome's javascript debugger.
2. What's the preferred way of formatting source code or any similar thing where you have to color individual characters differently, do you generally inline the formatting with perhaps spans or use javascript to parse and put the formatting elements around the relevant characters? Is there a third option I'm not aware of that is preferable to either of these?

Please let me know if this question doesn't fit or is off-topic so I can make any necessary edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question probably belongs on StackOverflow. Which, by the way, does exactly that...it has CSS just for formatting markup and code. StackOverflow uses Google Prettify to format and style code blocks http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: Sorry for posting in the wrong place! Thanks for pointing me to this though, that's exactly the kind of resource I figured existed but my google-fu was failing me heh